# Populating an array of structs passed to a function as a pointer

Tags: go, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-datastore

I'm want to do data pagination with Google Cloud Platform Datastore and I've found an example on GCP's page (https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/concepts/queries) for doing it with Cursors and it works absolutely fine.

The example provided by Google has hardcoded the variables `var tasks []Task` and   `var task Task` and I would like to create a **reusable** function where I can pass the pointer to a struct array via a parameter typed `interface{}` and get this struct populated by this function. For example:

```
    type MyStruct1 struct {
        F1 string
    }

    type MyStruct2 struct {
        F1 int
    }

    func list(ctx context.Context, cursorStr string, data interface{}) {
    ...
    }

    func main() {
        mystruct1 := make([]MyStruct1, 0)
        list(ctx, "", &mystruct1)

        mystruct2 := make([]MyStruct2, 0)
        list(ctx, "", &mystruct2)
    }
```

My problem starts when I need to create in this function, a variable to store the record and then append it to the struct array passed as a pointer.

**Example from Google**

```
func SnippetIterator_Cursor() {
    ctx := context.Background()
    client, _ := datastore.NewClient(ctx, "my-proj")
    cursorStr := ""
    // [START datastore_cursor_paging]
    const pageSize = 5
    query := datastore.NewQuery("Tasks").Limit(pageSize)
    if cursorStr != "" {
        cursor, err := datastore.DecodeCursor(cursorStr)
        if err != nil {
            log.Fatalf("Bad cursor %q: %v", cursorStr, err)
        }
        query = query.Start(cursor)
    }

    // Read the tasks.
    var tasks []Task << THIS IS WHAT I WANT TO BE GENERIC 
    var task Task. << THIS IS WHAT I WANT TO BE GENERIC 
    it := client.Run(ctx, query)
    _, err := it.Next(&task)
    for err == nil {
        tasks = append(tasks, task)
        _, err = it.Next(&task)
    }
    if err != iterator.Done {
        log.Fatalf("Failed fetching results: %v", err)
    }

    // Get the cursor for the next page of results.
    nextCursor, err := it.Cursor()
    // [END datastore_cursor_paging]
    _ = err        // Check the error.
    _ = nextCursor // Use nextCursor.String as the next page's token.
}
```

**My Generic function based on the code above**

```
func list(ctx context.Context, kind string, data interface{}, pageSize int, cursorStr string) string {
    query := datastore.NewQuery(kind).Limit(pageSize)
    if cursorStr != "" {
        cursor, err := datastore.DecodeCursor(cursorStr)
        if err != nil {
            log.Fatalf("Bad cursor %q: %v", cursorStr, err)
        }
        query = query.Start(cursor)
    }
    it := query.Run(ctx)

    // HERE IS WHERE THE PROBLEM STARTS
    var vet []interface{}
    var rec interface{}

    k, err := it.Next(rec)
    if err != nil {
        log.Println(err.Error())
    }
    for err == nil {
        log.Println(k, rec) // PROBLEM: The key comes ok but rec comes nil
        vet = append(vet, rec)
        k, err = it.Next(rec)
    }
    log.Println(vet) // PROBLEM: vet has only nils

    nextCursor, err := it.Cursor()
    if err != nil {
        log.Println(err.Error())
    }

    data = vet
    return nextCursor.String()
}

func TestListFunc() {
    data := make([]Tasks, 0)
    cursor := list(ctx, "Tasks", &data, 10, "")
    x, _ := json.MarshalIndent(data, " ", "   ")
    log.Println(string(x))
}
```

**PROBLEM:** The Datastore iterator `.Next()` doesn't seem to store the record in a variable typed `interface{}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [reflect](https://godoc.org/reflect) package:

```
func list(ctx context.Context, kind string, dst interface{}, pageSize int, cursorStr string) string {
    client, _ := datastore.NewClient(ctx, "my-proj")
    query := datastore.NewQuery(kind).Limit(pageSize)
    if cursorStr != "" {
        cursor, err := datastore.DecodeCursor(cursorStr)
        if err != nil {
            log.Fatalf("Bad cursor %q: %v", cursorStr, err)
        }
        query = query.Start(cursor)
    }

    // Get reflect value for the result slice.
    results := reflect.ValueOf(dst).Elem()

    // Allocate new value of the slice element type. 
    // resultp is pointer to that value.
    resultp := reflect.New(results.Type().Elem())

    it := client.Run(ctx, query)
    _, err := it.Next(resultp.Interface())
    for err == nil {
        // Append last value to results
        results.Set(reflect.Append(results, resultp.Elem())

        _, err = it.Next(resultp.Interface())
    }
    if err != iterator.Done {
        log.Fatalf("Failed fetching results: %v", err)
    }

    // Get the cursor for the next page of results.
    nextCursor, err := it.Cursor()
    // [END datastore_cursor_paging]
    _ = err        // Check the error.
    _ = nextCursor // Use nextCursor.String as the next page's token.
}
```

Call the function with a pointer to the destination slice:

```
var data []Tasks
cursor := list(ctx, "Tasks", &data, 10, "")
```

Comment: It works @ThunderCat! You're the GURU of reflection mate! Well done! Thank you very much!